How to type component's array prop which is array of union types to get correct typecheck
I'm trying to make a reusable card component which takes 1 to 3 charts of different type and using selector it displays currently selected chart inside the card. The problem is, I don't know, how to type correctly this component's charts property, which is of type charts: (LineChart | DonutChart | BarChart)[]; (array of union type)
Having these chart types separately (notice the extra prop in LineChartProps):
type LineChartDatum = string; //specificLineData
type BarChartDatum = number; //specificBarData
type DonutChartDatum = {
  name: string;
  value: number;
}; //specificDonutData

type ChartDatum = LineChartDatum | BarChartDatum | DonutChartDatum;

interface ChartProps<D extends ChartDatum> {
  data: D[];
}

interface LineChartProps extends ChartProps<LineChartDatum> {
  extraLineChartProp?: string;
}

interface BarChartProps extends ChartProps<BarChartDatum> {}

interface DonutChartProps extends ChartProps<DonutChartDatum> {}

I'd like the usage to be sth like this:
<Card
    charts={[
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.CURRENT,
            componentProps: {
                data: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                extraLineChartProps: "extra",
            },
            component: LineChart,
        },
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.WEEK,
            componentProps: {
                data: [1, 2, 3],
            },
            component: BarChart,
        },
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.QUARTER,
            componentProps: {
                data: [
                    { name: 'logs', value: 20 },
                    { name: 'vulnerabilites', value: 30 },
                ],
            },
            component: DonutChart,
        },
    ]}
/>

However when I type Card component like this:
export enum ChartCardSwitch {
  CURRENT = "current",
  WEEK = "week",
  QUARTER = "quarter",
}

interface LineChart {
  key: ChartCardSwitch;
  componentProps: LineChartProps;
  component: FC<LineChartProps>;
}
interface DonutChart {
  key: ChartCardSwitch;
  componentProps: DonutChartProps;
  component: FC<DonutChartProps>;
}
interface BarChart {
  key: ChartCardSwitch;
  componentProps: BarChartProps;
  component: FC<BarChartProps>;
}

interface CardProps {
  charts: (LineChart | DonutChart | BarChart)[];
}

typecheck won't pass following code (without any cast), because typescript expects that data prop will satisfy every possible union chart props data prop, even when from typing should be clear that component and componentProps must share same type:
<div className={'chartContainer'}>
    {activeChart && (
        <activeChart.component
            {...activeChart.componentProps}
            // How to get rid of this any and type Card component properly
            data={activeChart.componentProps.data as any}
        />
    )}
</div>

Posting also codesandbox for more straightforward use case understanding.

After digging a bit more on your codesandbox, I found out what was causing the trouble and forked a new sandbox here which now works.
So, the problem on my original approach (on the bottom) was caused by the way React infers types based on all available items in charts, creating intrinsicAttributes as an intersection type of all types from the properties and data, which was not compatible anymore with the union types.
In the new approach, I used an agnostic type for the charts, instead of using a generic one. This also means, you lose type-safety, but I couldn't find a way to keep the safety with intrinsicAttributes compatibility.
// chart.ts
export type ChartType = {
  key: ChartCardSwitch;
  componentProps: {};
  component: FC;
};

Another change is to avoid de-structuring data from the properties, because we're treating them in an agnostic way, and we don't care at that point what's the type of data.
So on the specific chart components we only pass the whole properties object as an argument and only care about the type inside the component. Here an example for BarChart:
// BarChart.ts
export type BarChartData = number;

export type BarChartProps = { data: BarChartData[] };

export const BarChart: FC = (props) => {
  const barProps = props as BarChartProps;
  return <div>{barProps.data.reduce((val, acc) => acc + val)}</div>;
};

The changes to Card:
// Card.tsx
export type CardProps = {
  charts: ChartType[];
};

export const Card = ({ charts }: CardProps) => { 
  // ...
  return (
      // ...
      <div className={"chartContainer"}>
        {activeChart && (
          <activeChart.component {...activeChart.componentProps} />
        )}
      </div>
      // ...
  );    
};

And on App.tsx you can use an array of ChartType for the charts:
const charts: ChartType[] = [
  {
    key: ChartCardSwitch.CURRENT,
    componentProps: {
      data: ["One", "Two", "Three"],
      extraLineChartProp: "extra",
    },
    component: LineChart,
  },
  {
    key: ChartCardSwitch.WEEK,
    componentProps: {
      data: [1, 2, 3],
    },
    component: BarChart,
  },
  {
    key: ChartCardSwitch.QUARTER,
    componentProps: {
      data: [
        { name: "logs", value: 20 },
        { name: "vulnerabilites", value: 30 },
      ],
    },
    component: DonutChart,
  },
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1>Hello StackOverflow</h1>
      <Card charts={charts} />
    </div>
  );
}

Original approach (not compatible in combination with FC's intrinsicAttributes)
I would create an interface and generics for the different kinds of data and the same for the properties, to cope with having some differences on the them too.
Something like this:
// first define the types of different data:
export type LineChartData = string;
export type BarChartData = number;
export type DonutChartData = {
    name: string;
    value: number;
};
// then create a type to use as a generic    
export type ChartData = LineChartData | BarChartData | DonutChartData;

// Then create a simple interface for the properties which include only data ...
interface SimpleChartProps<D extends ChartData> {
    data: D[]
}

// ...and then another one extending it for the line with extra properties.
interface LineChartProps extends SimpleChartProps<LineChartData> {
    extraLineChartProps: string;
}

// for simplicity, you can also declare extra ones for donut and bar:
interface DonutChartProps extends SimpleChartProps<DonutChartData> {}
interface BarChartProps extends SimpleChartProps<BarChartData> {}


// Then define a type for the properties and use it to define `Chart` 
type ChartProps = SimpleChartProps<ChartData> | LineChartProps;
// _or_ alternatively
type ChartProps = DonutChartProps | BarChartProps | LineChartProps;

interface Chart<P extends ChartProps> {
    key: ChartCardSwitch;
    componentProps: P;
    component: FC<P>;
}

You can now decalare the charts property of Card as:
    charts: Chart<ChartProps>[] = [
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.CURRENT,
            componentProps: {
                data: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
                extraLineChartProps: "extra",
            },
            component: LineChart,
        },
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.WEEK,
            componentProps: {
                data: [1, 2, 3],
            },
            component: BarChart,
        },
        {
            key: ChartCardSwitch.QUARTER,
            componentProps: {
                data: [
                    { name: 'logs', value: 20 },
                    { name: 'vulnerabilites', value: 30 },
                ],
            },
            component: DonutChart,
        },
    ]


Thanks for your suggestion @andzep, but this imho wouldn't work, if I wanted also some extra prop in some of the chart types. Edited issue and also codesandbox (added generics and also extraLineChartProp to demonstrate the problem). Also using suggested code, I wasn't able to type charts prop of Card component properly (there is a need to provide a generic type - charts: Chart<??>[].

Hi @Rokko, I missed the part with the extra properties for lines. I updated my answer accordingly.

Thanks for update @andzep but this approach doesn't work. Check out codesandbox which I update I believe 1:1 according to your suggestion. When creating charts constant as you mentioned, getting error (Type '({ data }: BarChartProps) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<ChartProps>'.) and so on for every chart type, since typescript want to satisfy every type listed in ChartProps union...

@Rokko yes, I wasn't using your sandbox to create my example, and I'm not familiar with react, so I wasn't aware on the problem with intrinsicAttributes. I updated my answer and created a new, forked sandbox.

thanks a lot for your new suggestions. I won't mark the answer as solution though since type-safety is important aspect for me and would like to see if anyone can come with solution that is type-safe as well

Yepp, I'd also really like to find out, if there's a way to achieve both :-)

By the way, I think, using class-based components instead of FC could maybe be the key to make it work. At least, it looked promising when I stumbled into them while learning about intrinsic attributes and FC components.
